# Archive Artifacts in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, artifacts

For archiving artifacts I am looking for the users of that artifact.
Published artifacts in feeds can be used or downloaded by others, is there a possibility to find out who they have been

Answer (score 0):

> is there a possibility to find out who they have been

I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this.

We all know that the artifacts in the feed can be used or downloaded. At this time, the package is only read and does not use write permissions.

In other words, it's like when we use repo, we only clone to local without modifying repo, so there will be no change to repo at this time, and there is no meaning of recording. Only changes made to the repo will have a commit record.

The same is true for packages in the artifact feed, and only when the package is modified will the information of who changed it will be recorded.

So, there is no such way to achieve this request.